# Do SN1 reactions have dependency on the nucleophile?

Tags: organic-chemistry

> 'The rate of the reaction of tertiary butyl bromide with the hydroxy ion is dependent on the concentration of the tertiary butyl bromide, but is independent of the hydroxy ion.'

This means that the rate of SN1 is independent from the nucleophile. Why does that happen?

Comment: 'tertiary butilic bromure' do you perhaps have an image/structure to accompany your quote? As is, the question doesn't entirely make sense. You might also like to edit the post to remove un-necessary capitalisation.

Comment: I'm guessing that "tertiary butilic bromure" is "tertiary butyl bromide", but please correct me if that's wrong.

Comment: see http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42566/does-a-reaction-have-to-have-a-rate-determining-step - Your 3 question stem from what is rate determining step of this reaction.