# How does a reaction exhibit kinetics with a non-integer reaction order?

Tags: kinetics

What does it mean when the order of reaction isn't an integer, e.g., a reaction order of 2.43. Not with something acting as a catalyst but rather as a inhibitor. Why does the inhibitor produce an unusual reaction order? Specifically fluoride ions slowing down the reaction between calcium carbonate and acid by forming calcium fluoride.

Comment: Never heard of the phrase "decimal point orders."  Reacting calcium carbonate with hydrofluoric acid would be slow since calcium fluoride is insoluble in aqueous solution. Hence the calcium fluoride would coat the calcium carbonate.

Comment: I guess I meant a fractional order with respect to an inhibitor? I've heard of the term broken order reaction but I've no definite source to reference

Comment: [Semi-related answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/32080/1499).

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the example reaction and data you are describing?